# Strcat(a[1],"22") how to use? C programming

Tags: c, strcat

i'm trying to make a program that if the previous letter is the same with the current letter that will be outputed will put a space between them...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define T 100
#define S 255

int main(){
char Arrayinput[T][S];
char Arrayoutput[T][S*5];
int i, c, x;
for(i=0;i<T;i++){
    for(c=0;c<S*5;c++){
        Arrayoutput[i][c]=0;
    }
}
scanf("%d", &x);
getchar();
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        gets(Arrayinput[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    for(c=0;c<strlen(Arrayinput[i]);c++){
            switch(toupper(Arrayinput[i][c])){
            case 'A':
                if(Arrayoutput[i][c-1]=='2')
                    strcat(Arrayoutput[i]," ");
                strcat(Arrayoutput[i],"2"); break;
            case 'B':
                if(Arrayoutput[i][c-1]=='2')
                    strcat(Arrayoutput[i]," ");
                strcat(Arrayoutput[i],"22"); break;
            case 'C':
                if(Arrayoutput[i][c-1]=='2')
                    strcat(Arrayoutput[i]," ");
                strcat(Arrayoutput[i],"222"); break;
}    }    }

for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    printf("case #%d:%s\n",i+1,Arrayoutput[i]);
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

for some case..

if i input..
bca it out puts 22 222 2 which is correct.. 
such as
cab = 222 22 2
bac = 22 2 222

but when ever i input
abc it out puts... 2 22222... i dont know why... pls help?

Comment: also i made all the arrayoutput[][]'s elemet to 0 so there will be no garbage data inside them.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the declarations of `ArrayInput` and `ArrayOutput`, as well as how you initialize them.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If there is something you do *not* understand regarding how [**strcat()**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) works from its documentation, you may want to include that in your question as well.

Comment: `Arrayoutput[i][c-1]  --> Arrayoutput[0][-1] for c=0` are you aware of this?

Comment: Also, learn to use a debugger, then you can step through the code line by line to help yourself find the problem.

Comment: Probably because of UB. When `c` is 0, `c-1` will result in -1.

Comment: First of all the first loop all checks `if(Arrayoutput[i][c-1]=='2')` evaluate a -1 position of array, means undefined behaviour.

Comment: im aware of -1, but why the heck the bca cba or any other order works fine just abc doesn't work as it is?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<T;i++){
      for(c=-1;c<S*5;c++){
       Arrayoutput[i][c]=0;
      }
     }`
i tried to include -1 for to make it 0 so there will be no garbage in it,, still print out the same issue.

Comment: No. Its UB meaning that anything can happen. For example, division by zero is undefined meaning that the results are unpredictable.

Comment: is there other way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply because of the `if(Arrayoutput[i][c-1]=='2')` of 'C' case with input abc will check always c-1 position, that is always " ".

- case A -> "2"
- case B -> "2 22"
- case C -> `Arrayoutput[i][c-1]` is `Arrayoutput[i][1]` that is a
  **space** then **no space added at the end of the string**.

**Try this**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define T 100
#define S 255

int main(){
char Arrayinput[T][S];
char Arrayoutput[T][S*5];
int i, c, x;
int len;
for(i=0;i<T;i++){
    for(c=0;c<S*5;c++){
        Arrayoutput[i][c]=0;
    }
}
scanf("%d", &x);
getchar();
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        gets(Arrayinput[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    for(c=0;c<strlen(Arrayinput[i]);c++){
        len = strlen(Arrayoutput[i]);
            switch(toupper(Arrayinput[i][c])){
            case 'A':
                if((len != 0) && (Arrayoutput[i][len-1]=='2'))
                    strcat(Arrayoutput[i]," ");
                strcat(Arrayoutput[i],"2"); break;
            case 'B':
                if((len != 0) && (Arrayoutput[i][len-1]=='2'))
                    strcat(Arrayoutput[i]," ");
                strcat(Arrayoutput[i],"22"); break;
            case 'C':
                if((len != 0) && (Arrayoutput[i][len-1]=='2'))
                    strcat(Arrayoutput[i]," ");
                strcat(Arrayoutput[i],"222"); break;
}    }    }

for(i=0;i<x;i++){
    printf("case #%d:%s\n",i+1,Arrayoutput[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: have you tried the code? because... it really does ticks me..
abc should be = 2 22 222 but print outs 2 22222 and others prints fine.. why is that thats all, serously.. yes it wont put if its not '2' but why doesn't it go through abc=2 22222 as it should be what i want it be?

Comment: The posted code works as you need. abc = 2 22 222. Compiled gcc 4.7.2 on Debian

Comment: I edited my answer. You have to think step by step. As edited the third check cheks the second char of the string that is "2 22". Then the if in case 'C' evaluets the space that is not == '2', the no space added at the string before to add "222"

Comment: i did found an alternative way.. though.. just printing them immedately.

Comment: Your question was about to explain you why your code was not working. I did it, and corrected your code. To have the same output with a different algoritm is another story, because of your code has 1000k of wrong things...